# Error: write EPIPE with node.js and imagemagick

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, imagemagick, epipe

I'm lost as to where this error is coming from, and I'm hoping you can help me. I'm new to node and am trying to resize an image with imagemagick:

```
var express = require('express'), 
fs = require('fs'),
gm = require('gm'),
imagemagick = require('imagemagick'),
var gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true });
var app = express();


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log(__dirname + "/public/photos/4af1e720-a662-11e3-952c-61812ab60f67.jpg");
    imagemagick.resize({
           srcData: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/public/photos/4af1e720-a662-11e3-952c-61812ab60f67.jpg", 'binary'),
           width: "400"
    }, function(err,stdout,stderr){
           if (err) console.log(err);
           fs.writeFile(__dirname + "/public/photos/thumbnail/4af1e720-a662-11e3-952c-61812ab60f67.jpg", stdout, 'binary');
    });
});
```

I get the following:

I've already checked that the folder thumbnail/ exists, and that the image exists. Do you know what else could be going on?

```
/Users/ik/Dropbox/snapgram/public/photos/4af1e720-a662-11e3-952c-61812ab60f67.jpg

events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: write EPIPE
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Object.afterWrite (net.js:720:19)
computername:snapgram ik$
```

Comment: Have you been able to find where is comming from yet? it's happening to me too.

Comment: I have exactly the same error randomly using a Meteor app on node.js. Any idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was getting this same error and discovered this issue:

https://github.com/aheckmann/gm/issues/209

You may need both imagemagick and graphicsmagick installed.  That solved my issue.

Comment: I installed graphicsmagick and imagemagick to windows but still getting the error.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure both imagemagick and graphicsmagick are installed on your machine.

To install graphicsmagick on ubuntu,

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dhor/myway
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick
```

Comment: I installed graphicsmagick and imagemagick to windows but still getting the error.