# imagemagick: running into Error: write EPIPE when passing in a buffer object

Tags: node.js, stream, imagemagick, buffer, graphicsmagick

Currently writing a node-based utility based on the [node imagemagick library](https://github.com/yourdeveloper/node-imagemagick) to take in a stream and output another stream to STDOUT:

```
im = require('imagemagick')
request = require("request")

sampleImage = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg"

request.get(sampleImage, (err, res, body) ->

    prefix = "-"

    switch (res.headers['content-type'])
        when "image/jpeg"
            prefix = "jpg:-"
        when "image/png"
            prefix = "png:-"

    taskHash = {
        srcPath: prefix
        srcData: body
        dstPath: -
        height: 100
    }

    callback = (err, stdout, stderr)->
        if err
            console.error(err)
            process.exit(1)
        console.log(stdout)

    im.resize(taskHash, callback)

)
```

Getting the following error:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: write EPIPE
  at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
  at Object.afterWrite (net.js:720:19)
```

Have noticed a similar error discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336461/error-write-epipe-with-node-js-and-imagemagick), but I think that this is a separate case, since I'm not using the graphicsmagick library. Is it not possible to use buffers without installing both imagemagick and graphicsmagick?

Answer (score 0):

node-imagemagick require two things:

- Node.js
- ImageMagick ;)

You have to install missing library (e.g. for Ubuntu):

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install imagemagick --fix-missing

It will solve your problem